# Remove emphasized text from bib entry

Tags: citing, biber, biblatex-chicago

I need to make a title of a @misc type bib entry not be emphasized in the footnotes if possible. I have managed to get it right when I print the bibliography using `\printbibliography`. I am using the footnote style using the `\autocite{}`.

Here is my preamble

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{article}

% PACKAGES ----------------------------
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[left=2.54cm, 
                        right=2.54cm, 
                        top=3.17cm, 
                        bottom=3.17cm]{geometry}

\usepackage[notes, short, backend=biber] {biblatex-chicago}% notes allows for footnote citation
\bibliography{RR1.bib}
\DeclareFieldFormat[misc]{title}{#1}

\ExecuteBibliographyOptions{%
    pagetracker=true, autocite=footnote,       abbreviate=true, alldates=comp,
    citetracker=true, ibidtracker=constrict,   usetranslator=true,
    usenamec=true,    loccittracker=constrict, dateabbrev=false,
    maxbibnames=10,   minbibnames=7,           sorting=cms, sortcase=false}

\usepackage{url}
```

My bib entry is in RR1.bib as

```
@misc{4.2.2,
    author      = {},
    title       = {Arch of Constantine, Inscription},
}
```

I'm not sure why the footnotes would still be italicized but the citation in the `\printbibliography` is fine. I am not sure how the `\DeclareFieldFormat` actually works.

I am using TeXStudio, Miktex, Windows. All my packages are updated.

Answer (score 1):

The title format in citations is sometimes controlled by `citetitle`, so you may want to redefine that format as well.

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}


\usepackage[notes, short, backend=biber] {biblatex-chicago}

\DeclareFieldFormat[misc]{title}{#1}
\DeclareFieldFormat[misc]{citetitle}{#1}

\ExecuteBibliographyOptions{%
    pagetracker=true, autocite=footnote,       abbreviate=true, alldates=comp,
    citetracker=true, ibidtracker=constrict,   usetranslator=true,
    usenamec=true,    loccittracker=constrict, dateabbrev=false,
    maxbibnames=10,   minbibnames=7,           sorting=cms, sortcase=false}



\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@misc{4.2.2,
    title       = {Arch of Constantine, Inscription},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}


\begin{document}
Lorem\autocite{4.2.2}
ipsum\autocite{4.2.2}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Arch of Constantine, Inscription.]